# Problem with path Dependency in Pyinstaller

Tags: python, machine-learning, pyinstaller, spyder, py2exe

I am currently working on "ubuntu 20.04". I have a classifier.py python file. My python file consists of machine learning packages like pandas, Sk learn etc. I have converted the python file (.py) into an executable file (.exe) using "Pyinstaller".

The generated .exe file works perfectly on my PC but when I try on another PC, it is depending on a path from my PC which is not present on the other PC, resulting in not working. The path is like Users/anaconda/lib etc.

Please help me, how can I solve the issue and also provide me with a good alternative like "Pyinstaller", "py2exe" etc wherein the other PC need not install the packages like Pandas, Sk Learn etc.

Is there a way that the other PC need not need even have python installed to run and executable will run along with files that the pyinstaller will create?

Advance Thankyou

Comment: PyInstaller is indeed supposed to package up the interpreter and all its dependencies. Does the other PC you're using have the same OS?

Comment: Same Ubuntu but diff version like 16, 18